# is it possible to sync to a serial bus using qt?

Tags: qt, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to input data from serial port and reply in 30ms only. I need to use a syncronous method to write out the data. I set up the buffer to 1 byte, is it correct?
but when i receive the data and write it out, it seems it is not in the given time frame.

Is there a special setting in QSerial ? i based my app on the terminal application ..

```
const QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();
m_console->putData(data);


qDebug () << QTime::currentTime() << "data to lin " << data.toHex();
for (const char y: data)
{
    uint8_t dataint = static_cast<uint8_t>(y);
    LIN_Input(dataint,m_serial);
}





/*  LIN_Input: gets the serial data as uint8_t
 *
 */
#ifndef UseQt
void LIN_Input(uint8_t ipbyte, nrf_serial_t const * p_serial)
#else
void LIN_Input(uint8_t ipbyte, QSerialPort *m_serial)
#endif
{
#ifndef UseQt
    Lin_serialcommunicatin = (nrf_serial_t *)  p_serial; //copy the pointer of the serial port
#else
     Lin_serialcommunicatin = m_serial;
#endif
    InitializeStructs();   // Initialize Arrays
#ifndef nodebug
//    qDebug() << ipbyte;
#endif

    if (DataLen>0)  // split data into coressonding bytes
    {
        if (ByteCounter<=DataLen) //while still receiving data as expected by its length
        {
            if (ByteCounter<DataLen) //not last packet
            {
                ByteCounter++;
#ifndef nodebug
//                qDebug() << "Packet #" << ByteCounter << " id =" << id << " data=" << ipbyte;
//                qDebug() << "Parsing";
#endif
                InputSerialData[ByteCounter-1]=ipbyte;

            }
            else                     // last packet ** CheckSum
            {
                CheckSum = ipbyte;
                uint8_t returnedchecksum =0;
                bool checksum = CheckCheckSum(ByteCounter, InputSerialData, CheckSum, &returnedchecksum); //check checksum
                if (checksum)     //checksum is correct, parse data otherwise ignore it
                {
                    for (uint8_t i=1; i<=ByteCounter; i++)
                    {
                        LIN_Parse(id,i,ipbyte); //lin_parser uses Bytenumber starting from 1 to 8
                    }

                }
                ByteCounter=0;
                id=0;
                DataLen=0;

            }
#ifndef nodebug
//            ByteCounter==0? qDebug() << "CheckSum " << ipbyte :
//            qDebug() << "ID=" << id << " Byte " << ByteCounter << " is " << ipbyte;
#endif
        }
    }


    if (Sync)       //was Sync the previous Byte? Yes-> Current Byte is ID
    {
        DataLen=LIN_Determine_ID(ipbyte,&id);
#ifndef nodebug
        DataLen>0 ? qDebug() << "ID=" <<ipbyte << " expect data with " << DataLen << "bytes" : qDebug() << "received id=" << id;
#endif
        Sync=false;
        if (id==0x47)
        {
            QTime q;
            qDebug() << ".............................";
            qDebug() << q.currentTime() <<  "ID 47 received";
#ifndef nodebug
            qDebug() << "ID 47 request, now reply";
#endif
            Lin_serialcommunicatin->waitForBytesWritten(10);
            LIN_Reply_ID47();
        }
        if (id==0x92)
        {
            qDebug() << ".............................";
            qDebug() << QTime::currentTime() <<  "ID 92 received";

#ifndef nodebug
            qDebug() << "ID 92 request, now reply";
#endif
            Lin_serialcommunicatin->waitForBytesWritten(10);
            LIN_SendSerialData(8);
        }
    }
    //Recheck the sync statemachine independent on previous byte: There was a bug here because it was made with else if there was no Sync in Previous Byte
    //consequence was not detecting sucessive syncs. Bug fixed.
    Sync = LIN_determine_sync(ipbyte,&State);

    if (Sync)
    {
        ByteCounter=0;
        id=0;
#ifndef nodebug
        qDebug() << "sync";
#endif
    }


}







void LIN_SendSerialData(uint8_t nofbytes)
{
#ifdef emulator
    qDebug() << "lin Send";
#endif
   //nofbytes = 2 or 8. Using <= because i send the checksum also
   for (uint8_t i=0; i<=nofbytes; i++)
   {
#ifdef UseQt
       //qDebug() << "byte " << i << " = " << SerializedData[i];
       QByteArray array(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&SerializedData[i]), sizeof(SerializedData[i]));
#endif

       //send_serial_data(SerializedData[i]);

#ifdef emulator
    qDebug() << "sending data to serial port =" << array << " hex=" << array.toHex();
#endif
#ifdef UseQt
         Lin_serialcommunicatin->write(array);
         QTime q;
         qDebug() << q.currentTime() <<  "Reply sent";
         qDebug() << " ............................. ";
#else
        char c;
        nrf_serial_t const * serialaddress = Lin_serialcommunicatin;

        c=(char) SerializedData[i];
        (void)nrf_serial_write(serialaddress, &c, sizeof(c), NULL, 0);
        (void)nrf_serial_flush(serialaddress, 0);
#endif
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First what OS are you using? Standard PC OSs have poor process timing. Meaning that when you get notified that data is available, you might have already lost 10ms.
Also if your serial goes over USB 2, you can loss an additional 8 ms because of the USB default polling rate of 125Hz. Which leaves you with only 12ms to send the data back.

Then looking at your code you do a lot of stuff before sending the reply and some of them can be time consuming.

For instance you do a lot of IOs by using `qDebug()`, each call will flush the output.
You also have a call to `InitializeStructs();` which by its name sounds like something that will take a lot of time.

The first thing to do is measure how much time you lose in your code and optimize the time consuming operations. To do this you can use external tools like callgrind or just use `QElapsedTimer::nsecsElapsed()`.

If it is not enough, you can try to increase the USB polling rate.

If you expect to receive multiple bytes of data before you have to send a reply, you can increase the buffer size.

If it is still not enough, you can reserve a CPU core for your thread doing the serial communications. Look for ISOLCPUS on Linux. I do not know if something similar exists on Windows. But I doubt, you should need this as 30 ms is not that critical.